# CMake: Cannot link to a static library in a subdirectory

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following folder structure in my c++ project

```
*--build
|---(building cmake here)
|
*--main.cpp
|
*--CMakeLists.txt (root)
|
*--modules
|---application
|------app.h
|------app.cpp
|------CMakeLists.txt
```

And the code below for both CMakeLists.txt files:

CMakeLists.txt (module)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15.2)
file(GLOB APPLICATION_HEADERS *.h *.hpp)
file(GLOB APPLICATION_SRC *.c *.cpp)

add_library(app_lib STATIC
            ${APPLICATION_HEADERS} 
            ${APPLICATION_SRC})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
```

CMakeLists.txt (root)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15.2)

project(main)
enable_language(C CXX)

#set directories 
set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR build)
set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES UNIX)
set(CMAKE_MODULES_DIR ${SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

# Build sub-modules
include_directories(modules/application)
add_subdirectory(modules/application)

find_library(MY_APP_LIB app_lib REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${MY_APP_LIB})
```

However, when I do `cmake ..` in my build directory, it seems like my app library just doesn't build and it doesn't link to it. I end up with the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:80 (find_library):
  Could not find MY_APP_LIB using the following names: app_lib
```

I tried looking at other stackoverflow questions but it seems like I'm missing something. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I should also mention that I don't see any files being generated by the app_lib library in the `build` directory and I'm not sure why.

Comment: how should ***any*** binaries created, if you don't even get throught the configuration phase with cmake. The build step is a seperate step happening after the configuration step. Even if configuration did complete successfully, there wouldn't be any binaries created, only the project that can be used to build the program (e.g. makefile project, visual studio solution, ..., depending on the generator used).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. It's due to my own misunderstanding of how cmake works. The reason I was confused is because if I removed the REQUIRED option, cmake will generate the files but will tell me that it couldn't link to app_lib. I assumed the app_lib was being generated but it couldn't link to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `find_*` to locate the library. In fact you cannot locate the library this way, since `find_library` searches the file system for the library ***during configuration***, i.e. before anything gets compiled.

There's good news though: If the targets are created in the same cmake project, you can simply use the name of the cmake target as parameter for `target_link_libraries`:

```
...
add_library(app_lib STATIC
            ${APPLICATION_HEADERS} 
            ${APPLICATION_SRC})

# note: this should be a property of the library, not of the target created in the parent dir
target_include_directories(app_lib PUBLIC .)
```

```
...
add_subdirectory(modules/application)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC app_lib)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do `find_library` for your own targets, just link directly to `app_lib`:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC app_lib)
```